# angular.js moment previous/next month navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I need to make a navigable calendar and i'm using angular moment library for date calculus.

I have the calendar but I need to make the previous and next month buttons. For now, I managed to find out the previous month but when I call the previous function, it will always return August (since it's subtracting 1 month from the current one I guess). How do I make this recursively using angular moment?

This is what I have and it will always return the previous month from september in milliseconds (it has to be in milliseconds).

This is my code:

```
$scope.firstDayOfTheMonth = moment().subtract(1, 'months').startOf('month').valueOf();
```

And I need to get the first day of the previous month recursively.

Comment: what do you mean "recursively"? I think what you are trying to figure out is how to subtract a month from the month your calendar is currently displaying, but you aren't showing what property that value is stored in here.

Comment: Yes, I have to subtract a month from current month and then again from the previous calculated month and so on. And then for next month the same, but this should be easier once I manage to do it for a previous month.

Comment: this question still doesn't make any sense.  The button only goes back one month per press, yes? And the calendar is on a specific month at the time of the press, which must be stored *somewhere*?  You should never have to do more than one calculation, and it is absolutely never going to be necessary to be calculating from the **real life** month, unless that is the one you are currently displaying....

Comment: for example, your calculation might look like `$scope.firstDayOfPrevMonth = moment($scope.currentMonth).subtract(1, 'months').startOf('month').valueOf();`